# Skipping a portion of image

Tags: image, text-extraction, python-tesseract

I was trying to extract text from an image using pytessaract, but it skipped a portion of image. But similar text was extracted from the same image. And when I made an image by cropping the skipped portion and extracted the text , all the text was extracted. Can anyone help me to figure out what is the reason. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Mmmm... you ran a command you didn't show us on some images we can't see and something went wrong. Come on, try a bit harder. Stack Overflow is a great resource of helpful enthusiasts who are willing to help anyone who makes an effort...

Comment: I understand your point Mark Setchell , please don't say i haven't made an effort. I tried whatever things are possible. Since this work is a confidential one , i am not supposed to share it. But Stack Overflow is my last hope. You got me wrong Mark.

Comment: I didn't say that, nor did I downvote, nor vote to close your question. I merely pointed out it is hard to work on something we can't see.

Comment: Mark it is extracting similar format text from the image but missed this one particular text. The only thing i can understand is that this text is isolated , there is not much other text near this text. And FYI am working with an engineering drawing of  a company, am trying to extract specific text from a whole pile of text.

Comment: Thank you Mark for making the comment. You are the only one who atleast made an effort to make a comment